# Dominant regular morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let V and W are affine algebraic varieties,
and f:V→W is dominant regular map V to W  and it is injective on a affine open set of V.
Then f induces isomorphism f*:RatV→RatW.

RatV means rational function field of V.

Is it true? If it is true,please show me how to prove it!

Comment: are you working in characteristic zero? I think Frobenius is a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: anyway, Theorem in Section 4.6 page 35 of Humphreys Linear algebraic groups seems what you need.